# Using the class methods of something in a TreeMap

Tags: java, treemap, treeset

I know there are already topics on this exact thing but none of them actually answer my question. is there a way to do this? 
if I have a TreeMap that uses strings as the keys and objects of the TreeSet class as the values, is there a way that I can add some int to a set that is associated with a specific key?

Well what I'm supposed to do is make a concordance from a text file using the TreeMap and TreeSet class. my plan is this use the TreeMap keys as the words in the text file and the values will be sets of line numbers on which the word appears. So you step through the text file and every time you get a word you check the TreeMap to see if you already have that key and if you don't you add it in and create a new TreeSet of line numbers starting with the one you are on. If you already have it then you just add the line number to the set. So you see what I need to do is access the .add() function of the set

something like

```
map.get(identifier).add(lineNumber);
```

I know that doesn't work but how do I do it? 
I mean if there is an easier way to do what I'm trying to do I'd be happy to do that instead, but I would still like to know how to do it this way just for you know learning and experience and all that.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following logic (I assume the input words are in an array):

```
TreeMap<String, TreeSet<Integer>> index = new TreeMap<String, TreeSet<Integer>>();
for (int pos = 0; pos < input.length; pos++) {
    String word = input[pos];
    TreeSet<Integer> wordPositions = index.get(word);
    if (wordPositions == null) {
        wordPositions = new TreeSet<Integer>();
        index.put(word, wordPositions);
    }
    wordPositions.add(pos);
}
```

This results in the index you need, which maps from strings to the set of positions where the string appears. Depending on your specific needs, the outer/inner data structure can be changed to HashMap/HashSet respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use a `Map` of `String` and `ArrayList<int>`, something like:

```
Map<String, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<String, List<Integer>>();
```

And then always when you get a word you check if it already exists in the `Map` and if it does exist you add the line number to the `List` and if not you create a new entry in the `Map` for the given word and the given line number.

```
if (map.get(word ) != null) {
    map.get(word).add(line);
}
else{
    final List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    list.add(line);
    map.put(word, list);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to have a treemap with each key referring to a treeset for storing line number on which the key has appeared. It is definitely doable and implementation is quiet simple. I am not sure why your `map.get(identifier).add(lineNumber);` is not working. This is how I would do it:

```
TreeMap<String, TreeSet<Integer>>  map = new TreeMap<String, TreeSet<Integer>>();
        TreeSet<Integer> set = new TreeSet<Integer>();
        set.add(1234);
        map.put("hello", set);
        map.get("hello").add(123);
```

It all works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason your construct won't work is because the result of `map.get(identifier)` can be null.  Personally, I like the lazy initialization solution that @EyalSchneider answered with.  But there is an alternative if you know all your identifiers ahead of time: for example, if you preload your `Map` with all known English words.  Then you can do something like:

```
for (String word : allEnglishWords) {
    map.put(word, new LinkedList<Integer>);
}

for (int pos = 0; pos < input.length; pos++) {
    String word = input[pos];
    map.get(word).add(pos);
}
```